# How to use alsa systemwide and still have a volume tweak

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

I have found that using alsa and not pulseaudio greatly improves the quality of my sound. I tested this using DeadBeef and "direct ALSA output". I'd like to have my entire system use ALSA directly instead of pulseaudio but, as I understand, pulseaudio is what provides the volume slider widget in my system tray.

Is there a way to set my system to use ALSA globally and still have access to a volume slider in the system tray?

I'm using a freshly installed Kubuntu 16.04 (KDE 5).

Answer (score 0):

The system is using ALSA already. Pulseaudio (or similar) is required to have multiple applications at multiple different volume levels, as ALSA is simply the hardware driver layer, and does not itself provide any software mixing at the application level.

To use ALSA directly for all applications, you would need to create a virtual loopback sound card for each application, which is not trivial, and would make dealing with volume control significantly more complex and frustrating. I don't know that any of the volume slider widgets for system trays of any environment support such a configuration.

Comment: the question didn't say anything about multiple different volume levels or software mixing.  i'm pretty sure we had global volume controls with alsa before pulseaudio was around.

Comment: Before pulseaudio was around, eSound (esd) was used. The question may not have asked about it directly, but when an app acquires the ALSA interface directly, other applications can't use it at the same time.

Comment: I know all that. This is what I am trying to avoid. Can't it be done without direct output to alsa?

Comment: "Without direct output to alsa" is exactly what pulseaudio does and is for.